# How did the addEventListener act in this module

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Edited:

Sorry, I didn't make myself clear,
now I re-think and re-write what I actually want to know:

When doing lesson from Odin project:

https://www.theodinproject.com/paths/full-stack-ruby-on-rails/courses/javascript/lessons/tic-tac-toe-javascript

I didn't understand why **addEventListener** in the gameBoard function auto-worked.

A simplified version of my code,

```
const gameBoard = (() => {

  window.addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert("2")
  })
})()
```

Why `window.addEventListener` auto-worked when I did nothing at all.

Comment: IIFE stands for Immediately Invoked Function Expression. So, the function expression is immediately invoked. The first snippet "works"; `gameArea` is created, and it has an `init` method available. It just doesn't alert "1" because `gameArea.init()` is never called. The second snippet "works" as well. It alerts "1" because `gameArea.init()` is called. Neither of those have anything to do with `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

People using that kind of code should be flogged to death with the complete works of Donald Knuth.

Decompiling that mess:

```
() => { alert("2") }
// an unnamed function that displays a popup. Let's call it Bob

window.addEventListener("click", Bob)
// This system call makes Bob the browser window click handler

() => { call Bob when you click on the browser window }
// yet another unnamed function invoking the above. Let's call it Bertie.

(Bertie)()
// Bertie gets called, setting Bob as the browser window click handler

const BoardGame = (Bertie)()
// BoardGame is assigned the return value of a function that doesn't provide any,
// thus being set to `undefined', which was also its previous value
// as a not yet defined variable, so this bit does not change much
// in the grand scheme of things
```

Instead of these hieroglyphs, you could have taken 3 minutes to give some names to these functions, like so:

```
function OnWindowClicked () {
    alert ("2");
}

function SetupWindowClickHandler () {
   window.addEventListener("click", OnWindowClicked);
}

const SomeUselessConstant = SetupWindowClickHandler();
```

There is exactly zero value to using lambda functions there, except maybe impressing the chicks with your mastery of pointlessly obfuscated JavaScript.

The idea behind using lambda functions is to [avoid cluttering the toplevel namespace with lots of function names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6077087/2960823), but there are other ways to do so. And besides, you don't need any of this to program a tic tac toe.

Quite the opposite: it makes for horrible, unreadable code while you'd be better off with simple examples to get familiar with the basics of the language.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you create a function and call it immediately.

```
const gameArea = (...)()
```

This function returns just another function called `init`.
So you didn't run init, only anonymous function that is now in gameArea.
To run `init` that you return you have to call it:

```
  gameArea.init()
```